# How to get edit view fields not to populate with existing data

Tags: cakephp

I have got the following code in my edit.ctp:

```
<div class="employees form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Employee'); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Edit Employee Details'); ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('id');
        echo $this->Form->input('employee_name', array('required'=>false));
        echo $this->Form->input('date_hired',array('required'=>false,'id'=>'datepicker','type'=>'text'));
        echo $this->Form->input('employee_phone_number', array('required'=>false));
        echo $this->Form->input('employee_email', array('required'=>false));
        echo $this->Form->input('employee_address');
        echo $this->Form->input('employee_dob',array('required'=>false,'id'=>'datepicker2','type'=>'text'));
        echo $this->Form->input('access_level', array('required'=>false, 'options' => array('admin' => 'Admin', 'staff' => 'Staff')));
        echo $this->Form->input('employee_username', array('required'=>false));
        echo $this->Form->input('employee_pw', array('required'=>false));
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
</div>
```

At the moment when I go in to the edit view, all fields get populated with existing data. I want the password field to be kept blank even if a password already exists. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo $this->Form->input('employee_pw', array('type'=>'password', 'value'=>'', 'autocomplete'=>'off'));
```